# C++ run link to run php script located in website

Tags: php, c++

I trying to run php script located in my website, run it there, but from local c++ app call

in c# i can use `Navigate("mysite.com/file.php");`

But now i need the same in c++, run hiddently this link to run the php script in to my webpage

y try this one but not work

```
system("open mysite.com/file.php");
```

Comment: unless you have a directory/folder and file called `mysite.com/file.php` system() is the wrong function, you should probably be using [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents) or curl etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone with `system` you could run any command, so the OP could use something like `system("curl …")`